# Postgress. HASH index type for text field

Tags: postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

Does HASH index add extra performance for the text datatype field with md5 string in it?

My usual request will be

```
select smt from table where hash_index_field = smt
```

In the table I have both the plain text column and hash of this plaintext.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash indexes *may* offer a slight performance advantage in some cases, but usually you are just as well served with a standard B-tree index.

If you want to know for sure, you'll have to benchmark your particular use case. It is impossible to give a "one size fits all" answer to such a question.